# JQuery TypeWatch plugin - Stop watching

Tags: jquery, typewatch

Is there a way to make this plugin to stop watching for changes in a determined textbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.off()` method:

```
$("#search").off('keydown paste cut input');
```

This will however remove all these event handlers attached to the element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/py76ddvq/)

Comment: Ok? Did it help you? Please set the answer as accepted if it did.